# 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<XDocument, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working on a asp.net core project with MongoDB.

I want to get a list from Database.

I tried this

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetRoomCodesFromHotelBooking(string transactionId)
{
  return HotelBookingCollection
    .Find(x => x.TransactionId == transactionId)
    .Project(x => x.Hotel.Rooms.Select(y => y.Code).ToList());
}
```

**Note :  A transactionId has more than one HotelBooking**

But I got this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<xDocument, System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

model class

```
public class HotelBookingDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public HotelDocument Hotel { get; set; }
// removed rest 
}

public class HotelDocument
{
    public List<RoomDocument> Rooms { get; set; }
// removed rest 
}

public class RoomDocument
{
      public string Code { get; set; }
// removed rest 
}
// removed rest
```

How can I  select room code and make list them?

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET Core because this question isn't directly related to ASP.NET Core. Re the problem: have you not tried `.ToListAsync()` with the appropriate `await`? P.S. I'm not sure the projection to list in the `.Projection` part is necessary.

Comment: yes I used `.ToListAsync()` but not works.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @hanushi could you add an example JSON document corresponding to your C# classes?

Answer (score 0):

You call `ToList` inside Project not for a Find cursor itself, ie the result of your operation is IFindFluent<..> not a server data. In fact, you even don't call a server yet until you will apply any operation for a created find cursor like `ToList`, `First` and etc